# Trouble updating Picker component from Async Storage in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I'm using a Picker component to let the user set a value for how frequently they want to be reminded about something. In the code below, I'm saving the result in the component's state as well as saving it to the device with Async Storage:

```
const [frequency, setFrequency] = useState('year');
```

...

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={frequency}
    style={styles.picker}
    itemStyle={styles.pickerItem}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => { 
        (async () => { 
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(`@circle_${circle.name}_frequency`, itemValue)
        })();
        setFrequency(itemValue);
    }}
    mode={'dropdown'}
    prompt={'Reminder every:'}
>
    <Picker.Item label="Never" value="never" />
    <Picker.Item label="Day" value="day" />
    <Picker.Item label="Week" value="week" />
    <Picker.Item label="Year" value="year" />
    etc...
</Picker>
```

I'd also like to have the component grab the saved data and set that as the state when first rendering.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchFrequency = async () => {
            let storedFrequency =  await AsyncStorage.getItem(`@circle_${circle.name}_frequency`);
            if (storedFrequency != null) { 
                setFrequency(storedFrequency);
            };
        }
        fetchFrequency();
    }, []);
```

Based on the limited amount I know about Async Storage, this seems to make sense. I think it's

- awaiting the result of grabbing the value from storage
- setting the state
- rendering the component (this could be happening before setting state as well, but I figure it would render again when the state changes)
- updating both storage and state when the user chooses a new option

However, this doesn't work. If I navigate away and then back to the page, the state has been reset.

UPDATE:

If I console.log the itemValue in the onValueChange async function this is what I get:

```
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => { 
                        (async () => { 
                            await AsyncStorage.setItem(`@circle_${circle.name}_frequency`, itemValue)
                            console.log(itemValue)
                        })();
                        setFrequency(itemValue);
                    }}
```

When changing the value to 'never', it prints

```
never 
never
```

When I navigate away and then come back, *without even touching the compnent* it prints out:

```
week
week
never
never
year
year
```

or

```
year
never
year
year
```

or some other long string of values which shows that there's a feedback loop going on somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was an issue with the Picker itself and how it calls onValueChange every render rather than only when changed. I found a temporary solution in this thread for until it gets fixed: https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select/issues/112#issuecomment-634038287

Answer (score 0):

Your expression `AsyncStorage.setItem()` is not firing because you forget to invoke Self-Invoking Functions inside the callback function of `onValueChange`.

```js
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => { 
        (async () => { 
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(`@circle_${circle.name}_frequency`, itemValue)
        })(); // I will invoke myself
        setFrequency(itemValue);
    }}
```

UPDATED (following the updated question):

I didn't spot any more bugs on your given snippet code and I don't know what's going on with your full source code. Anyway, I have created a super simple working snippet code following by the code in your question, so you can just copy into your project.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Picker, AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [frequency, setFrequency] = useState('year');
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFrequency = async () => {
      let storedFrequency = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@circle_circle_name_frequency');
      if (storedFrequency != null) {
        setFrequency(storedFrequency);
      }
    };
    fetchFrequency();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Picker
      selectedValue={frequency}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
        (async () => {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('@circle_circle_name_frequency', itemValue);
        })();
        setFrequency(itemValue);
      }}
      mode={'dropdown'}
      prompt={'Reminder every:'}>
      <Picker.Item label="Never" value="never" />
      <Picker.Item label="Day" value="day" />
      <Picker.Item label="Week" value="week" />
      <Picker.Item label="Year" value="year" />
    </Picker>
  );
}
```

Hope this can help!

PS: I see you put `expo` tag on your question and I just wanna remind that, if you preview the project on the web browser, your `storedFrequency` inside `useEffect` will always be `null` because the browser doesn't support `AsyncStorage`.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I missed that, but it doesn't fix the core issue. I'll update the thread with more info.

Comment: I've already updated the answer too, please check it out.

Comment: I appreciate the help! Testing this out on Snack led me to the answer. It looks like it was an issue with the Picker component itself. I've upvoted your answer but I don't have enough points for it to show.